# Datatables 'Search' searches through all rows in mysql table, ignores where condition

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using server side processing with Datatables.
My datatables picks rows from a view in my table where

```
username ='$session'
```

$session stores the current user's username.
This works fine and displays all rows with $session correctly but when I attempt a search it displays results from all users in my table.

I used the $where variable in ssp.class.php to perform the restriction and it works fine.

My question is how do you restrict a search to an sql condition?

Comment: How are you passing the search param to the server side code?

Comment: i dont pass a search parameter to the sever side code. Its just the default Datatables search box at the top

Comment: How can you use it in an SQL query if you don't pass it to the server side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

went through the flow again and I realized the WHERE condition wasn't appended to the global search part.

I added the condition to line 153 of examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php and it solved the problem.

```
$globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding." AND username = '$session'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass parameters to your php script. dataTables will do this for you and send pagination, sorting and filtering info to your script. (Just look at the request in the (firebug) console).

There is a function called `static function filter` in ssp.class.php which generates a mysql WHERE query for you.

At the end of this function the where clause is returned with `return $where;`

What you want to do is to add something like:

```
$where.= ' and USER = '.$username.' ';
```

before you return the `$where`.

(Watch out for the whitespaces to create/conactenate a valid query!)

`USER` should be the field in your DB and `$username` is the value from your session.

If both matches your data will be filtered correctly.

I can give you only this generic explanation since I don't know anything about your DB structure, what exactly is stored in the session or what version of dataTables your are you using. For debugging write $where to a log and you will see what's happening.

But this should give you a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: Yes I've concatenated my SQL conditions to the $where variable and it populates the table with the right data.
Now when i make a search, it returns rows that are outside the conditions i concatenated to the $where variable. That's the problem

Comment: Please show me the code where you do the concatenation and the generated where string. Everything else is guesswork.

Comment: session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {  //set the session variable
 $sessions= $_SESSION['user'];
}
$where = 'username = "'.$session.'"';

Comment: Sigh! You are not concatenating to the $where variable here, you are overwriting it. There is the concatenation dot missing. In the actual version 1.10.4 in the folder examples/server_side/script is ssp.class.php and at line 190 the $where is returned. You should add extra clauses in line 189. Then print the content of $where to your log and then send me the result of this variable after you have done a search.

Comment: it doesnt matter if it overwrites it. That is the only condition I'm using

Comment: No, you don't! If you are using ssp.class.php and want to have searching in your table, dataTables will transmit a lot of parameters to said class. Just look at the (firebug) console. You can either have a query that is limited to user filtering, or you use the server sided example code with searching and sorting and have to add the user filtering to ssp.class.php. Show us your code already and update your question or I'm outta here.